# Disable Standard Flow when creating new client in Keycloak with dynamic client registration

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid

When creating new client in Keycloak using Dynamic Client Registration, a new client has a **Standard Flow Enabled = true** and **Service Accounts Enabled = true**. That means that a client has **authorization_code** and **client_credentials** grant types.
But that is not what I expect.
I send a request to creat a new client with only client_credentials grant type, so only Service Accounts Enabled should be true.
Here is the example of the json value that I send to registration endpoint(*https://keycloak:port/realms/realm-name/clients-registrations/openid-connect*):

```
{"redirect_uris":[],"response_types":[],"grant_types":["client_credentials"],"application_type":"backend_to_backend","client_name":"test"}
```

Response json value example:

```
{"redirect_uris":[],"token_endpoint_auth_method":"client_secret_basic","grant_types":["authorization_code","client_credentials"],"response_types":["code","none"],"client_id":"afg6876c-c16b-4a40-b06b-85e758b2355b","client_secret":"fghIfqd0OG6gfKGIKjUzyutP76q6QbEu","client_name":"test","scope":"address phone offline_access microprofile-jwt","subject_type":"public","request_uris":[],"tls_client_certificate_bound_access_tokens":false,"client_id_issued_at":1693816447,"client_secret_expires_at":0,"registration_client_uri":"https://keycloak:port/realms/realm-name/clients-registrations/openid-connect/afg6876c-c16b-4a40-b06b-85e758b2355b","registration_access_token":...
```

My question is how to make a new keycloak client using Dynamic Client Registration with only client_credentials grant type and only Service Accounts Enabled = true?
Standard Flow Enabled flag must be false.
[Keycloak created client config example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUNrE.jpg)